# How to insert array in multiple rows in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, tags, jquery-select2

hi i need to insert an array in a table and i don't know how to do
i'm using the select2 plugin to select multiple values as tags and insert them in database as an array
the input looks like this

```
<select name="designation[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="select2"></select>
//script
$('#select2').select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
        selectOnClose: true
        });
```

EventController

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $validator = $request->validate([
            'theme' => ['required','unique:events,theme'],
        ]);
        $event = Event::create($request->except('designation'));
        $event->montant()->insert($request->get('designation'));


        return redirect()->to(route('admin.event.index'))
        ->withFlashSuccess('L\'éventment a bien etait ajouté');
    }
```

with this code when i submit the form i have this error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `event_montants` (`0`, `1`) values (222, 111))
event_montant migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('event_montants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->bigInteger('designation');
            $table->unsignedInteger('event_id');
            $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

please help i need to resolve this

Comment: `insert` is expecting an associative array where the keys are the field names, you are passing a zero-indexed array so it thinks your fields are named 0 and 1 ... not sure what field you are trying to save or why you would be trying to put an array in a single field

Comment: yeah i know but how can i change the key name form 0 and 1 to 'designation'? or convert this array to an associative array , cause when i debug $request->get('designation') it gives me this  
array:2 [▼
  0 => "222"
  1 => "111"
]
and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array containing numerous associative arrays to `insert` to insert multiple records. You will need to have these associative arrays with keys for the field you want. You could get your input, which is an array and map it to add get a final result with the field as the key as needed:

```
$data = array_map(function ($var) use ($event) {
    return [
        'designation' => $var,
        'event_id' => $event->id,
    ];
}, $request->input('designation', []));

$event->montant()->insert($data);
```

Though you may just want to loop through your array of inputs and call `create` instead of `insert` to not bypass the model and get your timestamps and model events fired.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the save method on the relationship.

Something like this:

```
$montants = $request->get('designation');

foreach($montants as $value) {
    $montant = new App\Montant(['designation' => $value, 'event_id' => $event_id]);

$event->montant()->save($montant);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for the help i just solved the problem with this code in the controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $validator = $request->validate([
            'theme' => ['required','unique:events,theme'],
        ]);
        $array_request = $request->get('designation');
        $array = array_chunk($array_request,1);

        $designation = array();
        foreach($array as $k => $v){
            $designation[$k]['designation'] = $v[0];
         }

        $event = Event::create($request->except('designation'));
        $event->montant()->createMany($designation);
        return redirect()->to(route('admin.event.index'))
        ->withFlashSuccess('L\'éventment a bien etait ajouté');
    }
```